# Python socket connection fails

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to implement a simple socket connection in python. In order to check it the client sends a sequence of 'o' and 'x.

My server script is the following:

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         # Create a socket
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind(('', port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)
c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
print 'Got connection from', addr                 
i=0
while True:
   str=c.recv(1)
   print str[0]
   print 'Got ',i
   time.sleep(0.1)
   i+=1
```

*i* is just a counter of how many characters the server has received.

My client script:

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host = "192.168.10.2" # Get local machine name
port = 12345
s.connect((host, port))

switch=0
while True:
    if switch:
        s.send('o')
        switch=0
    else:
        s.send('x')
        switch=1
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

My problem is that while the connection is absolutely fine in the beginning (the server receives and prints the characters as expected), after some time the server stops receiving data from the client and I cannot figure out why. The connection fails after about 650-750 iterations of the while loop of the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks !

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. Maybe add some print statements in your client code to make sure it's still working? Do you know how to use wireshark to see if the packets are still being sent?

Comment: What does it mean *"stops receiving data"*? Are both processes (server and the client) alive?

Comment: Turns out  the problem was caused by another command later in my code. Thank you both for helping though, I really appreciate it !

Answer (score -1):

The problem arises because the value of `i` goes to infinity. You can avoid this by adding a few lines in the while loop:

```
if i==100:
     i = 0
```